# the sum generated by jquery is only displayed but not saved in a textbox value

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Im using a wordpress plugin (kboard) by the way, and I'm just trying to include this function where the values that the user inserted in 3 text-boxes will be added using jquery, here's my code :

```
$(".add").keyup(function(){
var sum = 0;    
$(".add").each(function() {      
    sum += +this.value;
});

$(".total").val(sum);});
```

my problem is, the attribute "value" inside  is not changing, it only displays the sum. If I have to use ajax, what should my code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sum = 0;   
  $(".add").keyup(function(){        
        sum += +this.value; 
   });
$(".total").val(sum);
```

Initialize **'sum'** variable outside keyup function..

Comment: Why remove the + before this.value? OP is casting it as a Number so it does not get concatenated as a string.

Comment: thank you for your reply, im using a php plugin, so the values are being saved in a database on submit... the jquery is working but the value inside .total is not being saved, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Where .total is not being saved?

Comment: ah im sorry!! it's because i put disable="true" in my textbox (because i thought users should not be able to edit that textbox) , but then i changed it into 'readonly' and it was saved. ohmygahd. im sorry!! T^T

Answer (score 0):

```
// save (cache) this element in a variable for later use to save computation
var $values = $(".add");

$values.keyup(function() {
    // reset the sum
    var sum = 0;    
    $values.each(function() {      
        sum += +this.value;
    });

    // assuming total is an input, you can then set the value
    $(".total").val(sum);

    // if we're literally setting an attribute named "value", then
    $(".total").attr("value", sum);

    // if total is not an input and we're just updating its contents
    $(".total").text(sum);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I'm using a plugin where the values are saved into the database using php. jquery is working, but the value (sum) is not being saved, do you have any suggestions what should i use to save the sum jquery generated?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've seen my mistake, i re-read my code and i felt really stupid, ohmy. turns out it's because i put disable="true" in my input box that's why it's not saving when i should've used "readonly" oh my gahd. thank you for the answers though. such a stupid mistake. -__-